# Pause Excel graph while data is updating

Tags: sql, excel, vba, graph

I have lots of data that is pulled by a press of a button from SQL query through connections in Excel. Then I compose few simple calculations to get results. I also have 4 graphs that are based off that data.

I run into an issue where the code will take few minutes to execute. I believe it is due to the fact that while data is being updated, graphs are updated as well. I ran into that conclusion after removing graphs, it was significantly faster.

Is there a way to speed up this process a bit? Can I pause the graphing and resume it after all the data have been updated?

Thank you!

Comment: Store the last results and run the update under demand (button push) instead of at form load.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you considered offsetting the chart area in vba and switching back at the end of the code?

Here's how you can [Select the Chart Area](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841196.aspx) in VBA.

For example. If you want to chart data in Range A1:A10 then you can do the following

`Charts(1).SetSourceData Source:=Sheets(1).Range("B1:B10")`

```
your logic
```

`Charts(1).SetSourceData Source:=Sheets(1).Range("A1:A10")`

This "Aims" the chart at a different range so that it doesn't try to recompute the graph after each cell change. Once your logic is complete, then "Aim" it back at the correct range.

Comment: what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Upvoted because it's a good idea and to get Nate's reputation high enough to post comments.

Comment: Might as well edit this adding examples to make it a great answer.

Comment: I cleared any series and re-added them after updating the data. Still slows but much faster then before. I think calculations take most of the time. @Nate, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

And perhaps also

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

Before the query,
And reversing it after the query

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I did it was to clear all series in all the graphs at the beginning. Formatting stays the same on each graph.I created a sub that I call in the main program from where I am sending each chart variable name declared as ListObject and assigned a chart name.

```
Private Sub DeleteOldData(CurrentChart As ChartObject)
Dim s As Long

With CurrentChart
    For s = .Chart.SeriesCollection.Count To 1 Step -1
        .Chart.SeriesCollection(s).Delete
    Next s
End With
End Sub
```

Then, I update the data. After, I re-assign all the series back the graph through another sub.

```
Private Sub AddData(CurrentChart As ChartObject, table1 As ListObject, table2 As ListObject, series1 As String, series2 As String)

CurrentChart.Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
CurrentChart.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = series1
CurrentChart.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = table1.ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange
CurrentChart.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = table1.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange
CurrentChart.Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
CurrentChart.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Name = series2
CurrentChart.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Values = table2.ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange
CurrentChart.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(2).XValues = table2.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange
CurrentChart.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Select

DoEvents
End Sub
```

table1 and table2 are the tables from where I am pulling the data. I had to add 2 graphs on 1 chart from 2 different tables. Series1 and Series2 are the names for the series. I declared them before calling each sub.